# RegEx How to match string time duration with optional conditions

Tags: regex, typescript, time

I am having difficulty writing a typscript regular expression and would like some advice on how I can best achieve this?

I am trying to validate a string that contains a time duration 
e.g . `1y 3d 5m"`

- This may consist of any of the following preceded by a digit

  - y - Years
  - w - Weeks
  - d - Days
  - h - hours
  - m - minutes
  - s - seconds
  - ms - milliseconds
- it can contain `1 or more` of the following units
- They should occur in the order of greatest magnitude as listed above

  - `1y` must be before `1d`
- If more than one unit is present they must be separated by a space

  - **this is the bit i am having issues with**

I currently have the following but it doesn't correctly validate the required spaces, it allows for example `1y1d` which should be invalid.

`^[ ]*(\d+y)?^|[ ]*(\d+w)?^|[ ]*(\d+d)?^|[ ]*(\d+h)?[ ]*(\d+m)?[ ]*(\d+s)?[ ]*(\d+ms)?[ ]*$`

Examples

Correct:

- `1y 1w`
- `1d 1s`
- `1y 4d 2h`

Fails:

- `1y1w`
- `1w 1y`
- `2weeks`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
^(?=\d+[ywdhms])(( ?\d+y)?(?!\d))?(( ?\d+w)?(?!\d))?(( ?\d+d)?(?!\d))?(( ?\d+h)?(?!\d))?(( ?\d+m)?(?!\d))?(( ?\d+s)?(?!\d))?( ?\d+ms)?$
```

against your test cases.

```
 ^                       - string start
 (?=\d+[ywdhms])          - positive lookahead to prevent all emptyness
  (( ?\d+y)?(?!\d))?     - matches space + number + y, disallowes directly following number
  (( ?\d+w)?(?!\d))?     - matches space + number + d, disallowes directly following 
  (( ?\d+d)?(?!\d))?     - etc. spaces are optional, only enforced by negative lookahead
  (( ?\d+h)?(?!\d))?       for next number
  (( ?\d+m)?(?!\d))?
  (( ?\d+s)?(?!\d))?
  ( ?\d+ms)?$
```

It uses a positive lookahead to make sure the whole thing is not empty and after each  match a negative lookahead to make sure it can not be followed directly by the next number. Each match is optional as well. Convoluted, but I think it should work.

Fiddle: https://regex101.com/r/52D3Bm/1

It needs 1 space in between each matching part.

It will not prevent you from specifying `20485d` instead of normalizing them to weeks/years - do that in code behind.

Comment: Thanks, your answer is perfect and has explained it perfectly.

Comment: You probably want to follow the first `d` with a `*` such that it picks up all the digits before `[ywdhms]` and not just the last one.

The final expressions would become
`(?=\d*[ywdhms])(( ?\d+y)?(?!\d))?(( ?\d+w)?(?!\d))?(( ?\d+d)?(?!\d))?(( ?\d+h)?(?!\d))?(( ?\d+m)?(?!\d))?(( ?\d+s)?(?!\d))?( ?\d+ms)?`

Comment: @S..K that would void the purpose of the lookahead - \d* also matches for no digit at all. I changed it to \d+ so it will also work with multiple numbers before the first ywdhms in the lookahead.